# How Can my.css work along side jQueryMobile css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Using OSX 10.11.2, jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css "JQM"
 The code below produces the image on the left. But if I comment out the JQM I get the image on the right. both have some different functionalities which I need to combined:

1. float the right and left icons on the topBar and resize them.
2. fixed top and bottom bar not to scroll up or down.
3. style some boarders like in image 2.

if I use JQM, it cancels the css for 1 and 3, if I comment it out or even put it under the body tag, it cancels 2 and 3. I would like to include JQM for future use in my webApp which later will be converted to work inside a webView.

Could you please suggest a fix. Thanks

[image]

```css
.barTop, .barBottom {
   text-align: center;
   list-style-type: none;
   min-width: 320px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.barTop li, .barBottom li {
   height: 2em;
   line-height: 2em;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #c8c7c9;
}
.menuIconLeft {
   float: left;
   width: 2em;
}

.menuIconRight {
   float: right;
   width: 2em;
}

.menuIconCenter {
   width: calc(100% - 5em);
}

.barBottom li {
   width: 32%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>RRR</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myStyle.css"/>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
         <div class="header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
               <ul class="barTop">
                  <li class="menuIconLeft">
                     <b>&#9776;</b>
                  </li>
                  <li class="menuIconCenter">
                     Activity label
                  </li>
                  <li class="menuIconRight">
                     <b>&#8942;</b>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
         <div class="ui-content">
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, temporibus, dolore! Doloribus, at repellendus sunt consectetur modi natus suscipit magni explicabo optio sequi, assumenda delectus perferendis excepturi nisi nobis ratione.Lorem ipsum
               dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos repellendus aliquam sint atque aliquid, tempore voluptatum recusandae et rerum, qui quasi ex at aspernatur. Temporibus voluptatum exercitationem sit modi assumenda!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
               adipisicing elit. Laboriosam voluptatum illum maxime hic ipsa odio eaque cum. Optio cumque sequi recusandae. Nihil voluptatibus soluta ad saepe, quia optio laudantium molestiae.contents of this activity Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
               elit. Asperiores nulla facere soluta tempore nihil, voluptatibus nostrum sequi, voluptate, incidunt distinctio reiciendis qui at totam alias. Culpa fuga rem vitae nesciunt?
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <nav data-role="navbar">
               <ul class="barBottom">
                  <li>
                     <b>NO</b>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <b>EXTRA</b>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                     <b>YES</b>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to understand to solve this type of problem. Firstly, CSS prioritises whatever runs later - if you change a div background-color, and then change it again later, the latter change will apply.

Secondly, is the !important tag. By inserting it, you can force a certain aspect to override anything else that may apply to the code, for example;

```
height: 2em !important;
```

With any luck, you should be able to use this to solve your problem.

Comment: Adding !important to the selector (.barTop li, .barBottom li ) did not change any thing, sorry :(